# SAP ui5 custom headers dont arrive in the backend

Tags: odata, sapui5

I'm trying to send custom headers when I'm calling a create function in the odata service. I'm doing this to differentiate between certain create calls. The headers show up in the network tab in my browser but they arent there when I'm collecting all headers in the odata ABAP code.

Frontend code:

```
oModel.create("/EntitySet", oEntry, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "myHeader1" : "value1",
    "myHeader2" : "value2"
  }
});
```

[image: picture of my network tab]

Backend code

```
DATA: lo_facade         TYPE REF TO /iwbep/if_mgw_dp_int_facade,
      lt_request_header TYPE tihttpnvp,
      ls_request_header LIKE LINE OF lt_request_header.

lo_facade ?= /iwbep/if_mgw_conv_srv_runtime~get_dp_facade( ).
lt_request_header = lo_facade->get_request_header( ).
```

[image: picture of lt_request_header table results]

This is how i saw it in tutorials and it should work.. my question is why are the custom headers not in the request header table results?

Comment: Are you calling the ABAP service directly or through a proxy? The proxy could be removing the headers, could you try from the gateway client or postman? Also check for SAP notes, e.g. 2338409 might be applicable.

Comment: solved with note 2719624

Comment: @Hazed Please add an answer below explaining how you could resolve the issue. Then click on the check mark.